# JQuery masonry.js issue with Json data .append( )

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-masonry

I have tested masonry.js with multiple columns successfully but with my application I have the need to add masonry items dynamically using `.ajax()` JSON data. At the moment I have chosen to use `.append()` to layout the initial masonry .items -  The issue is that all of the masonry items are being output in a single column. The container size changes didn't help, even when increasing the amount of container width to more than enough, it will not style to 3 columns. Even when using the containerWidth function and using `return containerWidth / 3`

**Here is the code:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
 {     
      $.ajax(
      {
          url: 'http://localhost/project/index.php/controller/function',
          dataType:'json',
          success: function(data) 
          { 
        // limit - used to limit the json data ouput, as the json data contains an array of 50 objects.
            var limit = 11;
            $.each(data.results, function(index,item)
            {
                if (index > limit) return false; 

                // A bunch of var assignments mainly for data_*
            $("#content").append('<div class="item ' + index + '"><a href="' 
                    + data_link + '">'
                    + data_title + '</a><p>'
                    + data_desc + '</p><img style="height:100; width:100;" src="'
                    + data_img + '"><p>'
                    + data_date + 'Source: '
                    + data_source + '</p></div>');
            }); 
          }
      });
        $('#content').masonry({
            itemSelector: '.item',
            isAnimated: !Modernizr.csstransitions,
            columnWidth: 350
         }).imagesLoaded(function() {
            $('#content').masonry('reload');
        });
 });
```

**Here is the HTML in the view:**

```
<header> // FYI I am using CodeIgniter & Twitter Bootstrap
</header>
<div class="container" style="padding-top:145px; width:1300px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
<div id="content" class="container-mason clearfix">

    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Here are the styles I from masonry.js** - *changed `container` to `container-mason` in styl.css to avoid any possible conflict with bootstrap*

```
#container-mason {
   background: #FFF;
   padding: 5px;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   clear: both;
   -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
   border-radius: 5px;
}
<style >

#content 
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: auto;
}

.item {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 2px #0099cc solid;
     margin-bottom:10px;
    left: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
     border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-transition: left .4s ease-in-out, top .4s ease-in-out .4s;
    -moz-transition: left .4s ease-in-out, top .4s ease-in-out .4s;
    -ms-transition: left .4s ease-in-out, top .4s ease-in-out .4s;
    -o-transition: left .4s ease-in-out, top .4s ease-in-out .4s;
    transition: left .4s ease-in-out, top .4s ease-in-out .4s;
}    
</style>
```

**Thanks for the help!!**

**UPDATE**

**Here is the JsFiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/8CjT6/5/

Comment: Can you create a test case in jsFiddle?

Comment: Sure thing, Just a minute.

Comment: Here is the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/8CjT6/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have missed the style `float: left` for the items class.

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8CjT6/10/).

Comment: I have been racking my brain for the past 24 hours over this issue. You sir are a gentleman and a scholar. Fixed the problem exactly. Not sure how I missed that. Thanks!